# How to disable a radio button if another button is unchecked

Tags: javascript, radio-button

Ho to make the button unclick able except after checked one of radio button?
Please Help Me!

I HAve tried code below :

```
if(!radiobutton.isChecked){
  button.setVisible(false);
}
```

But its not help me..
anyone can solve my problem?

Comment: can you please explain in brief?

Comment: What environment are we in? Web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
  <div>
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkit" />
     <input type="button" value="click"  id="click" />
  </div>
```

Js:

```
        var check = $("#checkit");

       $("#checkit").on('click',checkStatus);

            function checkStatus(){

              if(check.is(':checked'))
                {
                   $("#click").prop('disabled', true);
                 }
             else{
                   $("#click").prop('disabled', false);
                }

             }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c6Az2/

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can disable other radio buttons if one is selected by giving same name attribute to all radio buttons.

```
<input type = "radio" name = "tiger"><label>Option A</label>
<input type = "radio" name = "tiger"><label>Option B</label>
<input type = "radio" name = "tiger"><label>Option C</label>
```

If you chose option A,other radio buttons will be deactivated.

Comment: How can you assume OP is concerned with an HTML answer?

Comment: As this is taged under button,I thought it will help him or someone else

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the button unclickable, try

```
button.Enabled = false;
```